# Background Worker's IsBusy property is not reliable

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have placed a check in the system

```
 public void ProcesssMessages(ResponseEventArgs message)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(message);

            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
```

Still it gives me error backgroundworker1 is already running and you can't run it twice. This is the only point in my screen where I run the background worker so there is no way someone in the meantime run it from other section.

Is there someway to make it safe or fail-proof.

I am not handling the completed event and thus there could be no way I am blocking that event. 
I cant run it in completed event as this is in a user control and someone access a method in this user control and I add that message in a queue. I then need to process that message using background worker, but first need to check if background worker is already processing the queue. Code for the background worker is

```
 void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (_queue.Count > 0)
        {
            ResponseEventArgs currentMessage = _queue.Dequeue();
            if (currentMessage != null)
            {
                AddUpdateDataRow(currentMessage);
                UpdateMainUI();
            }
        }
    }
```

Code for the UpdateMainUI method

```
   private void UpdateMainUI()
        {
            if (gridControl1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                gridControl1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(UpdateMainUI));
            }

            gridControl1.RefreshDataSource();
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Post the surrounding code. You're probably blocking processing of the Completed event.

Comment: Hard to guess what a "screen" has to do with this.  Making it fail-safe is pretty simple, just create a new instance of BGW.

Comment: That's not the code he meant, Henk was talking about the code around the 1st snippet.  Nevertheless, the 2nd snippet is notably bad, it is never safe to access a Queue in a worker thread without using a lock to protect it.

Comment: @HansPassant I've updated the code once again and accept that the code is notably bad because I didn't lock it. I want to make sure it won't hurt the Enqueue method in the meantime if I lock it while processing. I think if I lock it, I might break the meaning of using a background worker. It'll be then a synchronous processing. I am not very good in threading, please bear with me.

Comment: We'll need to see how `ProcesssMessages()` is called. And you do need locking around the queue, that won't hurt to threading here. `UpdateMainUI()` looks like a greater threat for that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman A window service is calling that method(ProcessMessages) asynchronously. Several threads from that service are calling this method.

Comment: There's just too many things wrong here.  This updated snippet shows how the "message" can get stuck in the queue.  Threading is going to eat you alive.  Only consider running AddUpdateDataRow() in a worker and only when it is really too slow.

Comment: _Several threads ... are calling this method._ - that is a problem, the IsBusy/RunWorkerAsync logic isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Then what could be the solution for this problem. And there is one more thing going on here in backgroundWorker1_DoWork method, when I dequeue the object. It returns null and I am very much sure while enqueuing it is not null.

Comment: @HansPassant When should I update the MainUI then?

Comment: Both your problems come from insufficient synchronization. Follow Hans' suggestion and drop the threading.

Comment: @HenkHolterman This does not answer my question. But avoiding suggestions from much experienced persons in this field like you and Hans is not going to do any good for me. Thanks to you guys for being helpful and patient.

Comment: We don't have enough information to post a better answer. You can google for `lock(){}` samples to solve the 2 direct problems here but I'm not sure that's the right course.

Comment: If this is being called from a windows service then your statement "This is the only point in my screen where I run the background worker so there is no way someone in the meantime run it from other section" is false and you should update the question.  Why not use a BlockingCollection?